# how to merge many folders and keep theirs contents sorted?

Tags: 16.04

I have a lot of folders that contain a lot of pictures, I want to put all the pictures under a single directory, but the folders contain pictures having the same name eg:

```
    folder1:
        -image1.jpg
        -image2.jpg
        -image3.jpg

    folder2:
        -image1.jpg
        -image2.jpg
        -image3.jpg
```

if there is any method to put all image under a single directory and keep all files sorted.like this example:

```
   directory:
      -folder1_image1.jpg
      -folder1_image2.jpg
      -folder1_image3.jpg
      -folder2_image1.jpg
      -folder2_image2.jpg
      -folder2_image3.jpg
```

I hope that I make it clear .thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find -exec`:

```
mkdir directory;
find folder* -type f -name "*.jpg" \
  -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" directory/$(dirname "$1")_$(basename "$1")' find-sh {} \;
```

Before:

```
.
├── directory
├── folder1
│   ├── image1
│   ├── image2
│   └── image3
└── folder2
    ├── image1
    ├── image2
    └── image3
```

After:

```
.
├── directory
│   ├── folder1_image1.jpg
│   ├── folder1_image2.jpg
│   ├── folder1_image3.jpg
│   ├── folder2_image1.jpg
│   ├── folder2_image2.jpg
│   └── folder2_image3.jpg
├── folder1
└── folder2
```

This has the obvious limitation that it is not working for e.g. `subdir1/folder` and `subdir2/folder`.

Comment: thank you very much. it works :D